# Linking iats payment to specific events

Tags: iats

My instance: civiCRM: 5.37.0, iATS Extension: 1.7.4, Drupal: 7.80

We organize and charge for events (each the same amount) and with civiEvent each event has a separate URL. The participant pays on line through iATS.

My iATS CreditCardJournal does not show for which event payment is being made. I would sure like to have the URL of the event (or similar tag) in the journal. Is there a way to do this?

I understand there are ways of linking the participant, payment and event within civiCRM using Summary Fields or hooking up to an accounting package but I'm inquiring about the iATS journal.

Answer (score 1):

The information as to what the payment was actually for (donation, event, membership, product purchase etc) only resides in CiviCRM. Payment processors don't care about what you purchase, they are all about authorization.

We do ship two reconciliation reports with the iATS Extension along with scheduled jobs that automatically pull the iATS journals into your CiviCRM instance. What you can then do (with the Report) is e.g. select Source -> and this will give you the Source field on the Contribution -> which typically contains the Event name.

[image]